# What is the Unique Identifier playerId in google-play-games?

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-oauth, google-play-games

I want to use the unique username of a user logged in using Google Play Games V2 as an identifier on my database.

After researching, I found that the [gamePlayerId](https://developers.google.com/games/services/web/api/rest/v1/players#Player) in the Player resource seems to be the identifier, but the current return value does not output that value.

POST https://games.googleapis.com/games/v1/players/me

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBZ5f.png)

I've also allowed next-gen player IDs in Google Play Console, but gamePlayerId is not exposed.
Is this really an identifier? It just needs to be a unique value for each time the user logs in in that game. In that case, is it okay to use playerId?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRRbz.png)

I check next-generator ID to use.